# Why does my local account lock after a session's timeout?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, user-accounts

I connect to my server (local account) by RDP :

```
PC -> VPN -> SERVER
```

Sometimes, when i've finished my work, I click on the cross to close the RDP session without loging off on the server.

Each time I did this, my account (server-side) gets lock and I've to connect to another account to unlock this one.

I've already read article about Account Lockout Policy, but I found nothing.

Have you any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: You are being restricted to a single session, not locked out.

Comment: @JimB Allright, so actually my session never gets kick off all the way and when a job is trying to interact with the session, it gets lock ?

Comment: Do you have to login with admin creds to unlock the account?

Comment: @JimB Yes i do.